# Syntax for replacing chars in variable names?

Tags: spss

I've got a problem with a bunch of SPSS files. Several of the variable names contains a '.' (dot) that I need to replace with underscore for SQL purposes.

I know there is the command `RENAME VARIABLE (varx = vara)`. So I'm thinking that there must be an "easy" way to loop through all variables and simply replace what I need replaced.

Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea of how SPSS Syntax works or if I need to use a macro.

It's a pain to do this manually, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to resort to writing a python script to natively do this in SPSS. Check out the [SPSS tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/spss/info) over at the stats.se site for some references to help get you started. Specifically the Programming and Data Management pdf will be of interest, as well as the SPSS specific forums. Unless your variable names are very standardized and predictable it would be a hard task to do this via a macro.

Comment: Ok. I've solved it another way by pasting the variable list into Notepad++ and, using block select, writing a separate `RENAME VARIABLE` for each one. It worked, but I don't like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a solution "[Remove underscores from all variable names.SPS](http://www.spsstools.net/Syntax/LabelsAndVariableNames/RemoveUnderscoresFromAllVariableNames.txt)" by Raynald Levesque. It requires some changes to work for your case. There are more solutions available at [www.spsstools.net](http://www.spsstools.net/SampleSyntax.htm#LabelsAndVariableNames).